# Wave nature of a typical ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, wave-particle-duality

how we can observe the wave nature of a typical tennis ball. Construct a thought experiment

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: i also thought that we cant measure the wave like nature of ball cause no matter what happens it cant be turned into particle so it remains wave so basically i thought that it was wave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculations with the Uncertainty Principle imply that the wave nature of a macroscopic object is too small for us ever to hope to detect.